# Start query from specific row java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to get the result after a specific number of query i.e

```
String sql="Select from mytable where sell_id = 
 '"+purchase_id+"'";
        java.sql.Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(res > 4){ //this line is where i still couldn't figured out
          String quantity = res.getString("quantity");
          String item = res.getString("item_name");
          String price = res.getString("price");
        }
```

but it shows an error "bad operand types for binary operator '>' "

```
| quantity | item   | price |
|    20    | soda   |   5$  |
|    10    | noodle |   7$  |
|     5    | water  |   3$  |
|    15    | gum    |   4$  |
|    14    | tissue |   2$  | 
|     2    | snack  |   6$  |
```

the result should be like this

```
|    14    | tissue |   2$  | 
|     2    | snack  |   6$  |
```

any suggestion will be accepted

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `res` is not a number. You're actually comparing an object to a number literal hence you're getting the error. If you want to loop into your result set you can do this:

```
while(res.next()){
    // do something here with your data
}
```

Comment: yeah i've been thinking about that also what code should i use to make the query starts from my decision (not from array [0] like default)

Comment: @Jokurilisme You could check Costis Aivalis' answer below. Also, you need to check if the same order of the data is being returned every time you query if it matters. If it does matter, I think you need to add an "order by" to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter which will check the condition as shown below:

```
int counter=1;
while(res.next()){
  if(counter>4){
      String quantity = res.getString("quantity");
      String item = res.getString("item_name");
      String price = res.getString("price");
  }
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
while(res.next()){ //anything you can think of!! }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to jump to the 5th row of your ResultSet, you can use:

```
res.absolute(5);
```

Since your are calling .next() after positioning and before getting data, your code would work like this:

```
String sql="Select from mytable where sell_id = 
 '"+purchase_id+"'";
        java.sql.Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        res.absolute(4); // will get your cursor to the 4th row

        while(res.next()){ // will get you to the 5th row and continue to the end
          String quantity = res.getString("quantity");
          String item = res.getString("item_name");
          String price = res.getString("price");
        }
```

A second alternative is to use the Limit clause at your select statement:

```
String sql="Select from mytable where sell_id = '"+purchase_id+"'" + " limit 4, 9999999999";
```

You will need no res.absolute(n) then, since the first res.next() will send you straight to the fifth row. I assume here that your table has less than 9999999999 rows. If it has more, then use a larger huge number.

Here is the API documentation for absolute(n):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

```
boolean absolute(int row)
          throws SQLException
```

Moves the cursor to the given row number in this ResultSet object.

If the row number is positive, the cursor moves to the given row number with respect to the beginning of the result set. The first row is row 1, the second is row 2, and so on.

If the given row number is negative, the cursor moves to an absolute row position with respect to the end of the result set. For example, calling the method absolute(-1) positions the cursor on the last row; calling the method absolute(-2) moves the cursor to the next-to-last row, and so on.

If the row number specified is zero, the cursor is moved to before the first row.

An attempt to position the cursor beyond the first/last row in the result set leaves the cursor before the first row or after the last row.

Note: Calling absolute(1) is the same as calling first(). Calling absolute(-1) is the same as calling last().

Parameters:
    row - the number of the row to which the cursor should move. A value of zero indicates that the cursor will be positioned before the first row; a positive number indicates the row number counting from the beginning of the result set; a negative number indicates the row number counting from the end of the result set
Returns:
    true if the cursor is moved to a position in this ResultSet object; false if the cursor is before the first row or after the last row

Throws:

SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed result set or the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if the JDBC driver does not support this method

Comment: String sql="Select from mytable where sell_id = '"+purchase_id+"'" + " limit 4, 9999999999"; this one worked for me thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What you need should be `ROW_NUMBER OVER ()`.

```
SELECT temp.col1, temp.col2, temp.col3 
FROM
SELECT 
    col1, col2,col3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS rowNum
FROM Table1 AS temp;
WHERE temp.rowNum > 4;
```